React with Web Components custom Methods Race Condition?
I am using web components, the component has a .selectItem() method, and I am hitting it from the ref from useRef. The problem I am running into is that I can't use that method later in my code unless I try and run it once.
useEffect(() => {
    if (countrySelectorRef.current && departmentSelectorRef.current) {
      countrySelectorRef.current.selectItems = countries;
      countrySelectorRef.current.selectItem();
      countrySelectorRef.current.addEventListener(
        'eds-single-select__item-selected',
        (e: CustomEvent) => {
          setCountry(e.detail);
          //Reset second dropdown on country select
          setDepartment('');
          departmentSelectorRef.current.selectItem();
        },
      );
      departmentSelectorRef.current.selectItems = departments;
      departmentSelectorRef.current.addEventListener(
        'eds-single-select__item-selected',
        (e: CustomEvent) => {
          setDepartment(e.detail);
        },
      );
    }
  }, []);

Without
countrySelectorRef.current.selectItem();

my later function to pull the data from query params and pre select the item wont work
useEffect(() => {
    if (
      countrySelectorRef.current &&
      departmentSelectorRef.current &&
      searchParams
    ) {
      countrySelectorRef.current.selectItem(searchParams.get('country'));
      departmentSelectorRef.current.selectItem(searchParams.get('department'));
    }
  }, []);

There has to be something I am missing in the rendering lifecycle as to why calling it fixes it to be used later one but without it on the ref it doesn't work?

It's hard to tell from the snippets you shared. How do the two useEffects relate to each other? (E.g. if they are in one component, then the second one is not "later" than the first one) What does the webcomponent.selectItem actually do? Also, if you add an event listener you should also take care of removing it later (this is general, not strictly connected to your issue).

Same component. React says make separate useEeffect per effect.
